# ¿Cómo puedo indicarle a un ciclo for cuantas columnas debe recorrer en php?

Tags: php, array, bucle-for, foreach, simple-html-dom

Estoy utilizando la librería de php simplehtmldom para extraer valores de una tabla que se encuentran en los html archivo1.html y archivo2.html. El foreach extrae la fecha, y el segundo for los valores. El punto es que los archivos NO siempre son iguales, y en este caso el archivo1.html tiene 2 columnas pero el archivo2.html tiene 4 (las que se ven reflejadas en los array iniciales que llevan sus mismos nombres.

```
$archivo1 = ['11040001-2_1', '11040001-2_12'];
$archivo2 = ['11120001-7_5', '11120001-7_7', '11120001-7_3', '11120001-7_13'];

$html = ['archivo1.html', 'archivo2.html'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($html); $i++) {
    $table = file_get_html($html[$i]);
    echo $html[$i . "<br>"];
    foreach ($table->find('<tbody><tr') as $tr) {
        $fecha = $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
        echo $fecha . "<br>";
        $col = 2;
        for ($o = 0; $o < count($archivo1); $o++) { // Puse a $archivo1 como ejemplo pero este deberia ir cambiando.
            $var = $tr->find('td', $col)->plaintext;
            $var = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $var);
            echo $var . "<br>";
            $col = $col + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

¿A alguien se le ocurre como puedo hacer para que el ultimo for detecte cuantas columnas son las que debe recorrer?

Comment: Lo estás haciendo correctamente con `count()`. Si tienes algún error o no está funcionando como esperas, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega más detalles.

Comment: Si el count es del archivo concreto sólo recorrerá los elementos que tenga ese array, independientemente del número. Otra forma es usar foreach en lugar de for, que hace el bucle mientras hay elementos.

Comment: @Triby Si pero porque puse directamente $archivo1, pero también necesito que automáticamente lo haga con $archivo2.

Comment: Precisamente, eso es lo que hace `count()`, devolver el total de elementos en un array, `count($archivo1);` devuelve 2 y `count($archivo2)` devuelve 4.

Comment: Ya entendí, voy con la respuesta.

Comment: @Carmen Exacto. Ya lo resolví y la solución fue implementar un foreach de vez de un for. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es crear un nuevo array que contenga $archivo1 y $archivo2, recorres ese array y dentro usas tu ciclo actual:

```
$archivo1 = ['11040001-2_1', '11040001-2_12'];
$archivo2 = ['11120001-7_5', '11120001-7_7', '11120001-7_3', '11120001-7_13'];

// Junta todas las opciones:
$archivos = [$archivo1, $archivo2];

$html = ['archivo1.html', 'archivo2.html'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($html); $i++) {
    $table = file_get_html($html[$i]);
    echo $html[$i . "<br>"];
    foreach ($table->find('<tbody><tr') as $tr) {
        $fecha = $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
        echo $fecha . "<br>";
        $col = 2;
        // Recorres todo lo que hay en $archivos
        foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
            // Luego recorres lo que hay en cada uno
            for ($o = 0; $o < count($archivo); $o++) { // tomará $archivo1 y luego $archivo2
                // Pero no veo que haces aquí con $archivo ni con $o
                // por eso dejé cu ciclo original
                $var = $tr->find('td', $col)->plaintext;
                $var = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $var);
                echo $var . "<br>";
                $col = $col + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Tal cual!, foreach fue la solución. Suponía que iba por ahí pero no sabia bien como implementarlo aquí. Gracias.